# Error parsing parameter '--change-batch': Invalid JSON + Route 53 DNS recordset update

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

When i try to execute below code, i am getting this error. Am i missing anything in the json format ?

````
 ```
 Error parsing parameter '--change-batch': Invalid JSON: Expecting value: line 7 column 14 (char 160)
JSON received: {
      "Comment":"To update private dns name recordset",
      "Changes":[
        {
          "Action":"UPSERT",
          "ResourceRecordSet":{
            "Name":devdnstest.test.com.,
            "Type":,
            "TTL":300,
            "ResourceRecords":[
              {
                "Value":"10.0.0.2"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
 }
````

```
    #!/bin/bash

#Variable Declaration
HOSTED_ZONE_ID="Z2UERB3PG6W9Y"
NAME="devdnstest.test.com."
TYPE="CNAME"
TTL=300

#get current recordset IP from Route 53
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $HOSTED_ZONE_ID | \
jq -r '.ResourceRecordSets[] | select (.Name == "'"$NAME"'") | select (.Type == "'"$TYPE"'") | .ResourceRecords[0].Value' > /tmp/current_route53_value

cat /tmp/current_route53_value

#prepare route 53 file
file=/home/route53_changes.json
cat << EOF > $file
{
      "Comment":"To update private dns name recordset",
      "Changes":[
        {
          "Action":"UPSERT",
          "ResourceRecordSet":{
            "Name":$NAME,
            "Type":$CNAME,
            "TTL":$TTL,
            "ResourceRecords":[
              {
                "Value":"10.0.0.2"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
 }
EOF
#update records
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $HOSTED_ZONE_ID --change-batch file://$file
```

In this code i am trying to update a private hosted zone record set from 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.2.
It's complaining about the "Type":$CNAME. But not sure what else to keep in there.
Appreciate your inputs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The data you're sending is not JSON - in particular,

```
            "Name":devdnstest.test.com.,
            "Type":,
```

There may be other tiny errors in there, but this will get you started.

In your original shell script, you'll need to add quotes and fix $NAME to $TYPE, something along the lines of

```
            "Name":"$NAME",
            "Type":"$TYPE",
```

For other people coming across this issue, you'll get a (slightly different) "Invalid JSON" message for syntactically correct JSON that doesn't conform to what AWS Route53 is expecting also.